# How do re-write whole current buffer with other buffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am trying to write my own `before-save-hook` binding function for formatting my code. I have found command-line application to do format.

So I am trying to

1. copy current buffer to temp file.
2. run command-line application to format temp file.
3. copy it back (overwrite) to the current buffer.

So I wrote this function but don't know how to copy file content back to current buffer.

```lisp
(defun my-format-before-save ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((filename buffer-file-name)
         (tempfilename (concat filename ".tmp")))
    (unwind-protect
        (progn (write-region (point-min) (point-max) tempfilename)
               (shell-command-to-string (format "some-format %s" tempfilename))
               ;;(???) ;; how to copy and over write current buffer with tempfile?
               )
      (delete-file tempfilename))))
```

Does emacs have this function to totally re-write the current buffer?
Is there another neat/elisp style way to reach my target?

Thanks

Comment: To me it looks like [Replacing buffer content without losing point](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/41102/31440) would be valuable for you.

Answer (score 0):

I use an additional step to read file to temp buffer and insert buffer to current buffer.

```lisp
(defun my-format-before-save ()
  (interactive)
  (when (eq major-mode 'my-mode)
    (let* ((filename buffer-file-name)
           (tempfilename (concat filename ".tmp"))
           (formatted-buffer (get-buffer-create "*formatted-buffer*")))
      (unwind-protect
          (progn (write-region (point-min) (point-max) tempfilename)
                 (with-current-buffer formatted-buffer
                   (erase-buffer)
                   (insert (shell-command-to-string (format "some-format %s" tempfilename))))
                 (erase-buffer)
                 (insert-buffer formatted-buffer)
                 )
        (kill-buffer formatted-buffer)
        (delete-file tempfilename)
        ))))
```

Looks like I have done with my target, except the cursor always back to (point-min) of the current buffer after format.